# Que veut dire « agrémenter » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

J’aimerais mieux comprendre comment je peux utiliser « agrémenter ». L’explication que le Wiktionnaire donne est un peu difficile. Celle du Trésor est étendue par contre. J’espère que quelqu’un peut m’expliquer de façon facile quel rôle ce mot joue dans le langage d'aujourd'hui. Voici ce que je pensais moi-même.

Je pensais que ce mot voulait dire qu’on enjolive quelque chose pour enlever les ornements quelques jours plus tard. Par exemple, enjoliver un arbre de noël, ou une chambre pour la parer pour une fête pour des enfants. Les guirlandes pendues sont débarrassées après une telle fête.

Je pensais aussi qu’agrémenter sert à rendre quelque chose agréable, plutôt qu’épater des gens au moyens des ornements qui coutent beaucoup d’argent.

Cela couvre un peu les sous-entendus de ce mot ? Et encore une chose, ce mot n’est pas vieilli, soutenu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrémenter est encore couramment utilisé. Voici la définition proposée par le Larousse :

> Pourvoir d'ornements quelque chose, l'enrichir d'éléments propres à le
>   rendre plus agréable, plus flatteur

Donc pour répondre à ta question, "agrémenter" **ne sous-entend pas** le fait *d'enlever* ces ornements après une célébration. Un deuxième sens est proposé par Larousse :

> Donner ou contribuer à donner plus d'agrément, plus d'attrait à
>   quelque chose

C'est le cas dans une situation où tu veux *agrémenter* un week-end de loisirs, par exemple, lorsque tu décides d'organiser un match de foot avec des amis. Par contre, cela ne fait pas nécessairement intervenir de l'argent ou quelque chose de cher.

Sources : [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/agr%C3%A9menter/1760)

Answer (score 3):

Simplement dit, agrémenter veut dire « ajouter , avec la connotation que c'est dans le but d'embellir (rendre plus agréable, plaisant), d'améliorer quelque chose.

Ce n'est pas un mot veilli, mais c'est un mot plutôt recherché, personnellement ce n'est pas un mot que j'entends souvent.

Dans l'exemple de Spadon_:

> tu veux agrémenter un week-end de loisirs

tu veux améliorer ton week-end en y ajoutant des loisirs.

« Agrémenter » n'implique aucunement que les améliorations doivent être enlevées par après.